# How do I theme user reset password page?

Tags: theming

How I can **template the user reset password page** when I receive the reset password token based link?

**/user/reset/2289/1545342420/zrmQkJAN9whwgu2xbKCW0KbIKigx7AsUgSo88UKr1c4**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wooha! I found the answer myself. These are the template file names which can be overridden to theme the pages.

**page--user--reset.tpl.php**
- To theme the reset password page when you will receive this of reset password URL in the email. /user/reset/2289/1545342420/zrmQkJAN9whwgu2xbKCW0KbIKigx7AsUgSo88UKr1c4

**page--user--login.tpl.php**
- To reset the user login page.

**page--user--pass.tpl.php**
- To theme the user password page when user enters the email address to recover the password.

See this for more information as well.
https://www.drupal.org/node/350634